# ProcessID Owner with third party app

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, windows

I am having problems trying to audit a third party app with a SQLServer backend.

The app manages users and user access via a SQL table, using a single SQL login to access the databases.

I am trying to audit this by using the Host PID much like Windows Task Manager associates a PID and Owner for every process.

Here is what I have attempted and tried

- I was able to figure out how to extract the `app.exe` PID.
- I cannot figure out how to get the Windows Owner associated to that PID.
- I have tried using `xp_cmdshell` to query the Windows tasklist and even wrote a .Net console app which gets called by SQL to collect the information but every time I try to extract the Owner it is blank.

Any thoughts on how I can get the Owner?

Comment: We went through this same exercise... as that 3rd-party app vendor; single SQL login, Windows apps, need to audit the user that's logged in. We ended up modifying the software to collect the data we need.

Comment: If the app is run from the users desktop (as opposed to a web app for example) then you could use the hostname to identify which workstation the connection is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot figure out how to get the Windows Owner associated to that PID.

You can get the owner using PowerShell:

```
# Identify the name of the remote computer you want to query
$computerName = 'SomeRemoteComputerName'
# Invoke the command on the remote system to get the information that is necessary
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -ScriptBlock {
    # Build a hashtable that associates process ids with owners
    $processOwners = @{}
    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process | ForEach-Object {
        $processOwner = $_.GetOwner()
        # Combine the domain and user information together to get the process owner
        $processOwners[[int]$_.ProcessId] = $processOwner.Domain + '\' + $processOwner.User 
    }
    # Now get all processes and add the owner information to them
    Get-Process | ForEach-Object {
        $processOwner = $null
        # If we have process owner information for the process, look up the owner in the table
        if ($processOwners.ContainsKey($_.Id)) {
            $processOwner = $processOwners[$_.Id]
        }
        # Add the owner information to the current process object
        Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Owner -Value $processOwner
        # Return the current process object from the script block
        $_
    } | Select-Object Name,Owner,Description
}
```

*[script source](http://powershell.org/wp/forums/topic/retrieving-process-list-and-owner-name/)*

Answer (score 0):

I assume your app is doing the user/password check as you said it manages the users. With extended events you can audit the login and every needed field.